# Weird behaviour when trying to find src attrib of img class

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to collect images of shoes, this is my code simplified:

```
browser.get('https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-men-s-shoes/tn/k0c18573?ad=')
recents = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel search-results-page__main-ads-wrapper user-ad-collection user-ad-collection--row']")
ads = recents.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a")

for ad in ads:
    img = ad.find_element_by_xpath(".//img").get_attribute('src')
```

It's very weird as it will find 'src' attrib of certain ads and it can't of others. I even tried this:

```
img = ''
while img == '':
    img = ad.find_element_by_xpath(".//img").get_attribute('src')
```

It will run forever. Any ideas of why this is happening would be appreciated

Comment: There different types of images in different sections. You need to update the question with the images you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code to query directly on the image elements of the ads, rather than trying to locate all of the nested elements. This is much more efficient.

I would also add in `WebDriverWait` to give your page time to load before locating image elements. Then, we can iterate image elements and get their `src` attributes.

Another thing to add here is the use of `ActionChains` to invoke `move_to_element`. The `img` elements on this website use lazy loading so the `src` attributes are not actually visible until we scroll to them.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.gumtree.com.au/s-men-s-shoes/tn/k0c18573?ad=')

# returns 24 image elements, one for each ad
most_recent_images = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//section[div/div[text()='Most recent']]/div/div/a//img")))

# declare action chains
#actions = ActionChains(browser)

for image in most_recent_images:
    # scroll to element
    #actions.move_to_element(image).perform()

    # scroll into view using javascript
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", image)

    # get src attribute
    print(image.get_attribute("src"))

browser.close()
browser.quit()
```

I ran this full code sample on my end and successfully printed 24 image links.

[image]

Comment: The issue here seems to be the lazy loading and the use of move_to_element fixes that so thank you!

Comment: One issue tho, when I run move_to_element in a loop, it moves to the element from the loop and every element before it. So when it's up to the 5th item, it goes to 1st then 2nd... etc until 5th. This is a problem as it'll take exponentially longer the further down the loop

Comment: Interesting, looking at the loop structure here and `move_to_element` should only happen once per element — if there were nested loops, I could see how that happens. Let me experiment with this code a bit and see if javascript `scrollIntoView` might be a better option for moving images into viewport. I will tag you again with my findings and a potentially updated answer!

Comment: @moo5e I ran the code and observed the same thing with `move_to_element`, it was quite strange. I replaced with Javascript and it runs much more quickly now.